# MySQL select * from table with specific key

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS color(
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;'

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS car(
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    colorId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (colorId) REFERENCES color(id)) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

How can I select names of cars with specified colorId and name of color from "color" table?

Comment: Do a JOIN between the tables, with a WHERE clause to pick the color of choice.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT car.Name 
      ,color.Name
FROM Car 
INNER JOIN color ON Car.ColorId = Color.ID
WHERE ColorID = ???  --<-- the color id you are looking for
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    car.name
FROM
    car
    LEFT JOIN color ON car.colorId = color.id
WHERE
    color.name = 'Red'
```

This query will return the names of cars that are red. Remember when inserting the color as a string to escape it properly (with [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)) to prevent [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: There's no point in using a left join when your `WHERE` clause requires a non-null value in the right-hand table...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the query with example. your can create your own

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS color(
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS car(
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    colorId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (colorId) REFERENCES color(id)) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

insert into color(name)
values('RED'),('BLUE'),('GREEn'),('YELLOW'),('PINK'),('ORANGE'),('WHITE'),('BLACK');

 insert into car(colorid, name)
 values(1,'BMW'),
(1,'AUDI'),
(1,'ASTON MARTIN'),
(4,'FERRARI'),
(3,'MUSTANG'),
(6,'SANTA FIEAA');

join Query..

select c.name, c.colorid, cl.name
from car c
join color cl on c.colorID = cl.id;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select car.name
 from car,color 
where color.name = 'red' 
and color.id = car.colorId
```

If you want to retrieve cars that are red.